# QT unable to connect to mssql server from qt application in ubuntu

Tags: sql-server, qt, odbc

Unable to connect to mssql server from qt application in ubuntu 20.04
Sql server located in windows 7
The connection is definitely present, because it was possible to connect through DDbeaver.

Can anyone help me in this situation?

Code:

```
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC3");


    db.setConnectOptions();
    QString serverName = "566***";
    QString ipName = "tcp:192.168.144.101,1433";
    QString dbName = "St***";
    QString connectionString =  QString("DRIVER={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};Server=%1;Database=%2;").arg(ipName).arg(dbName);

    db.setDatabaseName(connectionString);
    db.setUserName("sa");
    db.setPassword("top123TOP");
    if (db.open())
    {
        qDebug() << "Correct connection";
    }
    else
    {
        QString error = db.lastError().text();
        qDebug() << error;
    }
```

otuput is:

```
"[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Error code 0x2746 [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Client unable to establish connection QODBC3: Unable to connect"
```

odbcinst.ini

```
[ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql18/lib64/libmsodbcsql-18.0.so.1.1
```

Answer (score 0):

the following solution helped:

from:https://github.com/microsoft/msphpsql/issues/1112

```
This was helpful.

Ubuntu 20.04 PHP 7.4 using the 19.10 drivers for sqlsrv

We have a real old SQL server out there . The SQL Server show's version 10.50.2550.0, i think it's SQL Server 2008 R2. I had to use TLSv1 to connect to the server. I also had to do a "systemctl restart apache2" to get it to take affect. TLSv1.1 did not work with my MSSQL server version.

Error message: Connection failed: SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: [error:1425F102:SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol]Database Connection Error

edit: /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
1st line in the file added
openssl_conf = default_conf

End of file added

[default_conf]
ssl_conf = ssl_sect

[ssl_sect]
system_default = system_default_sect

[system_default_sect]
MinProtocol = TLSv1
CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1
Not 100% sure why i had to restart apache2 for it to take effect, but I had to.

systemctl restart apache2
reloaded the page and it works
```